# traverse bash array including empty elements

Tags: arrays, bash, is-empty, quoting

```
array=('' '' 2 4); for f in ${array[@]}; do echo a; done
a
a
```

I expected four "a" rows here as there are 4 elements of array

$ echo ${#array[@]}

```
4
```

Comment: `"${array[@]}"`. many many duplicate questions will be found.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Also, please follow this advice from the tag info before asking questions with [tag:bash]: "For shell scripts with errors, please check them in http://shellcheck.net before posting here."

Comment: Thank you rici, shellcheck gave right answer. I didnt notice that advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must quote the variable for correct using:

```
array=('' '' 2 4); for f in "${array[@]}"; do echo a; done
```

and btw. search for simular answers :)

Comment: Thank you. Was unable to find. Honestly.